# How do I use deluge to parse the products list in a Zoho Sales Order (or PO, quote, invoice, etc.)?

Tags: zoho

I'm able to look at a list of products, but I can't seem to deal with them individually.  Is the object being returned not a normal deluge list?

This works:

```
salesorder = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Salesorders",input.so_id.toLong());
lineitems = salesorder.get("product");
```

But neither of the following lines will save (Zoho doesn't bother displaying an error message):

```
salesorder = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Salesorders",input.so_id.toLong());
lineitems = salesorder.get("product");
liCount = lineitems.size();
for each lineitem in lineitems {}
```

Is there another way to loop through line items in these kinds of modules?

Comment: When I send the salesorder object in the body of an email, the product attribute is enclosed in square brackets.  Does that indicate that it's a list or something else?  ... "Status":"Delivered","product":"[{Product Id=1663763000000192212, Discount=0.0 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop the items in a Zoho order or invoice like so:

```
items = invoice.get("product").toJSONList();
for each item in items
{
    itemMap = item.toMap();
    name = itemMap.get("Product Name");
}
```

Comment: Does that work?  I don't have access to Zoho anymore to check.  Are you sure that it doesn't result in a flat array instead of a hierarchical JSON object?

Comment: It works. Just implemented it recently, but it's not hierarchical. That's why you must cast the iterated item using the .toMap() method.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a nice-looking option, but it does seem to work.  Now, I just need to figure out how to use deluge to update the line items with new data.

```
salesorder = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Salesorders",input.so_id.toLong());
lineitems=salesorder.get("product");
li_list=lineitems.subString(1,(lineitems.length()  -  1)).toList("},{");
for each rec in li_list
{
    lineitem="{" + rec + "}".toMap();
    product_id=lineitem.get("Product Id");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
salesorder = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Sales_Orders", input.so_id.toLong());
```

// Line items are available in the response with key "Product-details". The value is the list of products.

```
orders = salesorder.get("Product_Details");
productList = Collection();
```

//Iterate through the line items contained in the collection with key "product"

```
for each order in orders
{
    productList.insert(order.get("product"));
}

info productList.size(); // 2
info productList; // {"Product_Code":null,"name":"test","id":"44206000000114102"},{"Product_Code":null,"name":"001","id":"44206000000114160"}
```